# Struggling with subquery & joins

Tags: sql, join, group-by, subquery

I'm working on a problem set for my data class and I keep getting the 'missing expression' error code. Here is what I've written:

```
select c.numbkids "Number of Kids",
       (select avg(r.rating)
        from netflix.ratings100 r join netflix.movies_genres m on r.movieid = m.movieid
        where m.genrecode like 'ACT'),
       (select avg(r.rating)
        from netflix.ratings100 r join netflix.movies_genres m on r.movieid = m.movieid
        where m.genrecode like 'ADV'),
       (select avg(r.rating)
        from netflix.ratings100 r join netflix.movies_genres m on r.movieid = m.movieid
        where m.genrecode like 'COM'),
       (select avg(r.rating)
        from netflix.ratings100 r join netflix.movies_genres m on r.movieid = m.movieid
        where m.genrecode like 'MYS')
from netflix.customers c join netflix.ratings100 r on c.custid = r.custid
where c.numbkids < 4 and
group by c.numbkids
```

I am displaying families with only 3 or fewer kids (column 1), and I need to display the average rating that each family size has given the action genre (column 2), adventure genre (column 3), comedy genre (column 4), and mystery genre (column 5). It seems to me like I need to use subqueries to group each of those genre columns by number of kids before taking their average, but I don't know how to do that without adding additional columns. Please help!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.  You can use conditional aggregation, which in the standard uses `FILTER`, but in most databases uses `CASE`:

```
select c.numbkids "Number of Kids",
       avg(case when m.genrecode like 'ACT' then r.rating end),
       avg(case when m.genrecode like 'ADV' then r.rating end),
       avg(case when m.genrecode like 'COM' then r.rating end),
       avg(case when m.genrecode like 'MYS' then r.rating end)
from netflix.customers c join
     netflix.ratings100 r
     on c.custid = r.custid join
     netflix.movies_genres m
     on r.movieid = m.movieid
where c.numbkids < 4
group by c.numbkids
```

Comment: You're a life saver! I've also tried taking the average of a subquery (obviously didn't work), not sure how I didn't think to take the average of a case. Thank you!